# nginx redirect to another host with params?

Tags: nginx, redirection

i need to redirect

http://auth.foo.bar/verify/:id/:name/:domain

to

http://auth2.foo.bar/api/verify/:id/:name/:domain

where :id, :name and :domain are variables. any advice on this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append the end of the first url like this:

```
rewrite ^/verify/(.*)$ http://auth2.foo.bar/api/verify/$1
```

you can of course do a more complicated rewrite like this

```
rewrite ^/verify/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ http://auth2.foo.bar/api/verify/$1/$2/$3
```

This makes it possible to change the order of the three variables